# SQL that returns highest volume and lowest price

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE customerQuote(
                           quoteID char(36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
                          ,customerID char(36) NOT NULL
                          ,quoteNo INT
                          ,volume int
                          ,price decimal(6,2)
                           );
```

- A `customerID` has many `quoteNo`.
- Each `quotNo` has many entries.
- Price and volume will vary.
- The same `quoteNo` may also have multiple entries for the same volume, but with different price.

Now I need a query that returns `customerID`, `quoteNo`, highest volume and the lowest price for the highest volume.

An example: 
A customer (customerID) has quotes:
`quoteNo=55 and quoteNo=62`

Those quotes have these entries:

```
quoteNo=55; volume=90; price=1.52
quoteNo=55; volume=25; price=1.65
quoteNo=55; volume=90; price=1.50
quoteNo=62; volume=99; price=1.40
```

For this particular customer I want the query to return:

```
customerID, 55, 90, 1.50
customerID, 62, 99, 1.40
```

Yes, I know the system is messy as it allows multiple entries for the same customer with the same volume, but that is real life, and the reason I need this query.

Comment: This ref. to sql server 2012.

Comment: I have tried different combinations of MAX and MIN, but end out listing the wrong combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a derived table:

```
with mv   -- The derived table finds the quote with the highest volume.
as
(
    select customerID
            ,quoteNo
            ,max(volume) as maxVolume
    from customerQuote
    group by customerID
            ,quoteNo
)
select c.customerID      -- Which you then use to find the lowest price at that volume.
        ,c.quoteNo
        ,mv.maxVolume
        ,min(c.price) as minPrice
from customerQuote c
    inner join mv
        on c.customerID = mv.customerID
            and c.quoteNo = mv.quoteNo
            and c.volume = mv.maxVolume
group by c.customerID
        ,c.quoteNo
        ,mv.maxVolume;
```